# How to compare two titles (strings) to see if they refer to the same book?

Tags: python, string, pattern-matching, string-comparison, difflib

I am trying to compare two titles (from different sources) of the same book, for each book in a huge list of books, to see if they refer to the same book or not.

Here is a little background. I am working as an intern in a library. The staff here scanned the Accession Number and ISBN of each book and gave it to me as a csv file. Due to human error, some books got the wrong ISBN. I am supposed find those mistakes.

For each accession number, I know the correct Title from our library management software. For each ISBN, I pulled out the titles from the internet. Now I want to compare the two titles to know if ISBN of a different book has been scanned in place of the real one.

I currently use the `SequenceMatcher` class in `difflib` do this:

```
def similar(seq1, seq2, strength):
    return (difflib.SequenceMatcher(a=seq1.lower(), b=seq2.lower()).ratio()
                > strength)
```

But I get a lot of false positives like:

> "Communication networks: fundamental concepts and key architectures"
>   =>     "Communication networks"
>
> "Experiments in Engineering Physics ; A Laboratory Manual and Workbook >with Viva Voce" => "Experiments in Engineering Physics"
>
> "Water: science and issues" => "Water V1 - V4"
>
> "Schaum's outline of theory and problems of statistics" => "Theory and >problems of probability and statistics"

Is there a better way to do this?

Edit: [Here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/19476678/) is the output of my program with all the false positives. I used '##' as a delimiter.

Comment: It seems that your error is systematic. Therefore you can check for a match of a) either the whole sequence or b) the sequence until the first " : ".

Comment: It would help if you could post some samples, i.e. title from the library software vs. title from the internet. It's hard to help without knowing what the differences are.

Comment: @Rawing Done, thanks for the suggestion...

Comment: @NikolasRieble I was thinking that there would be some intelligent algorithm which already exists that can do this. You are right, 80% of the false positives fall in your description, and I  will do that if I don't get any other elegant solution. I've made my examples broad to include other cases, and also posted a paste of my entire output.

Comment: I do not know about an existent algorithm to solve this issues, yet I would propose to increase the information for comparison. You can calculate a similarity score based on several attributes besides the title. This information could be: author, publisher, etc.